# Debugging a Maven WAR project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, maven, jboss

I've recently begun to use Maven for dependency management and structure for my Java EE 6 applications.  I'm a relative newcomer, but have successfully managed to create projects for a Java EE 6 EAR with WAR, 2x EJB, and utility modules and am able to deploy it to JBoss EAP 6.2 with no problem.

One area I am finding rather difficult is in JSF development.  Previously, when I would create an EAR/WAR project in Eclipse, it was very simple to deploy the app, make changes to the *.xhtml files, publish the changes, and see them reflected immediately just by hitting the Refresh button on my browser.  This made it easy to test content layouts, etc. on my JSF pages.

With Maven, however, I find myself having to do a Maven 'install' to repackage my EAR and deploy it for every little change.  Is there no way to have Eclipse/JBoss recognize the src/main/webapp folder from my Maven project and use that for the JSF path so I can do development and debugging easier?

For the record, I am using JBoss EAP 6.2 as my app server, and Eclipse Kepler for my IDE with JBoss Tools installed.  I have not added any other Maven or JBoss plugins beyond that.

Comment: Are you not using m2eclipse?

Comment: I believe that is what I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a web maven archetype project if you have the **m2eclipse** plugin installed.  That kind of project has a pom.xml that drives the entire show and generates the appropiate eclipse configuration for you to deploy the project (or just drag and drop it) into your app server.

There are even jsf specific archetypes to choose from in m2eclipse.

Comment: How do I go about doing this?  I'm certainly able to open my projects up in Eclipse with no problem.  I created them using the Maven wizard within Eclipse, so that was never an issue.  How do I go about deploying the project to JBoss?  Do I just right-click and say "Run on server" like I would a non-Maven project?

Comment: Of course!  If you have created it with the appropiate archetype, it should work :)